# Is it possible to add a local .git folder to a TFVC project, but still use TFVC in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, tfvc

I have a project that is managed in TFVC. I would like to use git locally via git bash. I don't care about syncing the git repository anywhere for now, however, I still want to keep the connection to TFVC. I don't care much about Visual Studio git integration. I would like to use Visual Studio mainly with TFVC.

Whenever I add a `.git` folder (e.g. via `git init`) to my project folder, Visual Studio (at least 2019 and 2022) decides that this solution is managed by git and not by TFVC. The source control explorer becomes unavailable.

I tried adding the `.git` folder to `.tfignore` via `.git`, `.git*`,`\.git` and `\.git*`, however, Visual Studio insists that the project is controlled by git and not by TFVC. Once I delete the local `.git` folder, Visual Studio happily goes back to TFVC.

Comment: ¿Why do you run `git init` if you don't want your solution to be managed by git?

Comment: Why not use something like `git tfs` to have a local Git repo, but sync to and from TFVC?

Comment: @user7860670 As mentioned, I want to use git locally. The project is maintained by many people. It is not my decision how it is managed on server side and it is not essential to me. It would be a nice way to show people some git features locally, without having impact on daily processes.

Comment: @DanielMann thank you for suggesting `git tfs`. If the answer to my question is indeed "no", I will certainly consider that.